# Macro to detect availability of class properties in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, clang, class-properties

Xcode 8 introduces Objective-C class properties and I would like to add one to an Objective-C library.

However I would like the library to still compile with Xcode 7. Is there an availability check I can do at compile time?

Something like

```
#if __hasFeature(objc_class_properties)
@property (class, readonly, nonatomic) MySingletonClass *shared;
#endif
```

What does work is:

```
#if __clang_major__ >= 8
```

…but I'd like to check for feature availability rather than CLANG version.

Answer (score 4):

Searching the [LLVM source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang) I found:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_class_property)
```

…which works perfectly.