# How to access Objective-C class properties in runtime?

Tags: objective-c, llvm-clang, objective-c-runtime

Thats what I have:

```
@interface Example : NSObject

@property (class) NSString *classProperty;

@end
```

And trying to access class property:

```
Class meta = objc_getMetaClass(class_getName([Example class]));
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty(meta, "classProperty"); // == nil
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(meta, NULL); // == nil
```

I am using Xcode 8 and iPhone 7 iOS 10 Simulator and just wanna access class properties with Obj-C runtime functions.

I have read some slides here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/405/
And read some info here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/objective-c-class-properties/

Also checked `#if __has_feature(objc_class_property)`, and it has: [Macro to detect availability of class properties in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131390/macro-to-detect-availability-of-class-properties-in-objective-c/39131517#39131517)

**UPDATE:**

Strange things happens: today this code works fine. I am sure yesterday I had a moment when it works, but later it was not.

**UPDATE 2:**

Read my own answer below.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @NulledPointer I am working on DI framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found absolutely different behaviour when setting `Deployment Target` to iOS 8 and iOS 9+. Objective-C runtime have no information about class properties when `Deployment Target` is set to iOS 8, and have all necessary info when `Deployment Target` is set to iOS 9+. So framework I am working on will become iOS 9+.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually do this. Class properties cannot be synthesized  nor are they auto synthesized. You're responsible for implementing the getter/setter or using @dynamic. This appears to be syntactic sugar for class level getter/setter methods and hence are not showing up.

I wonder if this is a temporary thing?

What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working on DI framework, and wanna achieve dynamic property injection